# jquery grid of images on click to show each specific content, but only shows 1 section

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

Hello so I am trying to create an about us page.

There is a grid of thumbnail images, and when you click on one thumbnail the content for that thumbnail appears about the set of thumbnails. Each thumbnail have their own unique content.

I currently have this working but when you have 1 thumbnails content, if you click another thumbnails content that ALSO appears.

I am just wanting one set of the thumbnails content to appear, not multiple.

I apologise if this is very easy, I cant find the answer...

Any help will be massively appreciated :)

Have a look at my codepen of what I have just now -

```
`enter code here` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNWXYp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant fix but: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNdmry

Your problem here is that you are only referencing the clicked object, therefore it will only hide/show the specific object being clicked. To fix this I've simply added an array of potential displayed objects and on each click this is checked and any that are identified are hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        var array = ['#john', '#jane', '#agent', '#peter'];
        var i = 0;
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                toggle_switch.html('Show');
            } else {
                for (i; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (array[i] != collapse_content_selector) {
                        if ($(array[i]).is(':visible')) {
                            $(array[i]).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
                toggle_switch.html('Hide');
            }
        });
    });
});
```